Big Query: Load data into existing table
I am exploring Big Query in the Sandbox to see if it's a good fit. I've been reading through the documentation, the forum here and elsewhere and cannot figure out how to load data into an existing table. This would be an overwrite, not append. For this exploration, the data is either a csv, or google sheet (no preference just for this test).
All of the examples I find are for creating a new table. I already have the table/schema defined. I just want to load data into that existing table. Any leads are appreciated.
I've tried the create table process a few times with the understanding there is an option under the Advanced menu for overwrite. That option does not exist.

Have a good read at these two articles.  Take your time and contemplate them.  Once done, update your question relative to questions you may have on interpretation of the articles:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#sql

In the "Advanced options" of the create table process there should be a drop down field "Write preference:" with three options "Write if empty", "Append to table" and "Overwrite table". Can you confirm?
